# How do you redirect to the same controller method in playframework using Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

When opening the url

```
/users/{id}/foo
```

I will display the view with a call to

```
html.foo(userWithId)
```

In the controller method foo I want to make sure that id is the same as the loggedin user's id and if not should redirect the user to

```
/users/{theLoggedInUsersId}/foo
```

using

```
html.foo(loggedInUser)
```

works fine but this is not a redirect, so the url in the browser still is

```
/users/{id}/foo
```

I want to really redirect so that the url is showing the correct id. I'm not sure how to do this. Using "Action" like this:

```
Action(foo(loggedInUsersId))
```

will get an error for using recursion without supplying a return type. Adding the return type play.template.Html to the controller method foo, will get a compiler error since Action returns a ScalaAction and not Html.

How should I do this. Should I even do it, am I stuck thinking about it in the wrong way?

### Edit

The Redirect(...) works fine. But is it possible to do without it?
In pseudo-Scala:

```
def list(id: Long) = {
  if (some_criteria)
    html.list(user_with_id_equal_to_id)
  else if(another_criteria)
    list(another_user_id)
  else
    Action(Application.login)
}
```

The list(another_user_id) won't work since it's a recursive call and I have to supply a return type on the list method. Adding the return type *play.templates.Html* won't work since that is not the return type of *Action*

Do you see what I'm getting at? If I instead of using a call to *list* uses html.list(user_with_another_id) then it won't be a redirect and the url in the browser will still be /users/id/foo instead of /user/another_id/foo.

Comment: And did you try with Redirect(url) directly? Looking at play code, I think it's easy to find how to get an URL from an action...

Comment: Hey Jörgen Lundberg, I'm sorry I'm not entirely following you.  I've looked over your code several times.  The Action should work.  The Action will send a redirect from another method.  html.blahblah will not send a redirect.  It will just render a scala template.  So you have to call Action.  I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding you.  What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: It's the recursive call to 'list' in the else if statement in the middle. Then I have to have a return type on the list-method. The problem is that html.list and Action don't have the same return type.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is check that the id is equal to the logged-in user if so, list some stuff, if the id is for another user redirect to list with the logged in users id, else redirect to the login-page. I'm not sure it makes sense... :) I'm probably attacking the problem in the wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to go about doing this.  The first is to use the Redirect return type.

```
Redirect("/find/user/" + id)
```

The way you want is to use the Action like you suggested.

```
Action(findUser(id))
```

This should work fine.  Play actually resolves this call as URL and calls a redirect.  So the first example I showed you is pretty much the same thing.  The Action works better because it prevents you from having to change code if you change the url.  We may need to see more of your code to see what's going on.

Here is a more clear example.

```
    def index( userId : Option[ String ] ) = {  

    Action(findCurrentUser(userId.getOrElse("test@test.com")))
}

def findCurrentUser(userId : String) = {

    User.find( "email = {email}" ).onParams( userId ).first() match {

        case Some( user ) => Json( user )

        case None => Error( "Could not find current user" )
    }
}
```

Reference: http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/controllers#Returntypeinference

Comment: Actually in Play 2.0, you should do:
Redirect(routes.ControllerName.findId(id)), where ControllerName is the name of your Controller object

Comment: This was a question for Scala support in Play 1.x, 6 months before Play 2 came out.

Comment: I know, I just thought it was useful to have the answer in Play 2 for those who stumble on this.